# mode of a column in a dataframe based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mode

Imagine I have a dataframe called 'countries' with multiple columns including the country and their respective idiosyncrasies.

```
Country   Idiosyncracies
Brazil    We love football
France    We love love
Italy     We love Pizza
Italy     We love Pizza
Italy     We love Gellato
Brazil    We love festivals
Italy     We love Pizza
France    We love bread
France    We love bread
France    We love bread
Italy     We love Gellato
Italy     We love Pizza
Brazil    We love football
```

For each country, I would like to extract the mode response(idiosyncrasy) into another dataframe as shown below

```
Country    Top comment        
Brazil     We love football    
France     We love bread       
Italy      We love Pizza
```

This is the piece of code I tried

```
grouped = countries('Country')['Idiosyncracies'].mode()[0])
```

However, instead of getting a (3,2) dataframe, I get an error message of

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) for select first value:

```
df = (countries.groupby('Country')['Idiosyncracies']
               .apply(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
               .reset_index())
print (df)
  Country    Idiosyncracies
0  Brazil  We love football
1  France     We love bread
2   Italy     We love Pizza
```